# Unable to connect FTP: 530 Login incorrect

Tags: linux, ftp

My account has been created on a LINUX server and I am able to login through putty. I have changed my password also. But, to move a file there, I tried to connect that server through FTP client. I used **Winscp** as well as **Fireftp** both. But, there is no luck.
I provided information like below"

```
Hostname:myhost.example.com
username:myusername
password:mynewpassword
Mode: passive
Port: 21
```

When I checked the port, I found that Port 21 is open on that server.

Please help me about how to connect FTP successfully on this LINUX server. Where I am making mistake?

Comment: Username & password work when you SSH into the system?

Comment: If you get `530 Login incorrect`, that means that you *did* connect. You just weren't allowed to login with the user/password combination you used. Ask the person/s in charge of the server to check their logs to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Having a user inside a *NIX operating system does not mean that you will have ftp access.

Does this system have a ftp server running(probably yes, since tcp-21 is opened), and it is configured to integrate with pam or other of your login management system? Some ftp servers use logins that are not related with the ones created on the operating system. Other systems will require a specific shell to enable you to login using ftp. There is a ton of options that could explain why you are not accessing...

If you are able to login using putty(ssh tcp-22) you could use scp meanwhile to move things to your home directory on that server. WinSCP have support.

Comment: I am getting `Access denied` message when follow your instructions in WinSCP.

Comment: scp is not different than a ssh session. Is there a way to contact your system administrator? It seems that you may have missed your password or something like that...

Comment: Given he's getting a 530 error and port 21 is open would seem to indicate that the server is up.

Comment: That is why i explained that i can be some kind of integration between the ftp server and the server PAM or other login management system