# How to know user type in LINUX machine

Tags: sudo

My account has been created on a LINUX machine. But, I don't know which type of user I am ( root user or normal user) and which type of access I have.
Is there any command through which I can check whether I have **sudo** access or not in a linux machine if I already have an account.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sudo -l` to determine what level of capabilities you have assigned within its configuration.

From `man 8 sudo`

```
   -l[l] [command]
        If no command is specified, the -l (list) option will list the 
        allowed (and forbidden) commands for the invoking user (or the user 
        specified by the -U option) on the current host.  

        If a command is specified and is permitted by the security policy, 
        the fully-qualified path to the command is displayed along with any 
        command line arguments.  If command is specified but not allowed, 
        sudo will exit with a status value of 1.  

        If the -l option is specified with an l argument (i.e. -ll), or if 
        -l is specified multiple times, a longer list format is used.
```

Comment: After executing `sudo -l` command, I have to input password and then it display message - `sorry, user may not run sudo on servername`.

Comment: That means you have no special privileges enabled by the sudo configuration.

Comment: Does sudo access required for FTP connection?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question :) Making an outgoing FTP session from the server or incoming to the server? Plain FTP or SFTP? Setting up an FTP server?

Comment: Yes, I raised a separate question too. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124248/unable-to-connect-ftp-530-login-incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Try the command "id" to see which groups you are in. This will give you an idea about the account you are using.

```
id -a
```

Answer (score 0):

To see which groups you are part of try `groups`.  Whether or not you have access to `sudo`  depends on your local configuration.

If when running `groups` you don't see `wheel` or `admins` `staff` or a group  specifically  set up fir`sudo` access then you likely haven't been automatically granted `sudo`-ing rights. Note that those can be added via the `sudo` configuration as well.

Comment: If I run `groups` command, I can see only my username in the output list.

Comment: You are part of a group that has the same name as your username. If you don't see `wheel` or `admins` `staff` or a group  specifically  set up to have `sudo` access then you likely haven't been automatically granted `sudo`-ing rights. Note that those can be added via the `sudo` configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can type groups to see you groups

```
[user@system ~]$ groups
users
```

and you can just try to use sudo and see, wheater you have sudo access or not. You could try it with "ls". If you don't have sudo access you get an error:

```
[user@system ~]$ sudo ls
```

Comment: If I run above command (`sudo ls`) - it prompting for the my password. When I input my password, system prompt message like - `users not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Comment: This means, you do not have sudo access.